# If an algebra is derived equivalent to a (special) biserial algebra is it biserial?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

A (finite dimensional) algebra is called biserial, if the radical of each projective indecomposable left/right module is the sum of two uniserial modules whose intersection is either trivial or simple.

It is known that a certain subclass of algebras (called gentle algebras) is closed under derived equivalence.

What about this larger class of biserial algebras? Is there an example of an algebra derived equivalent to a biserial algebra which is not biserial?

(What about the subclass of special biserial algebras?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, in general.  A simple counterexample is provided by a path algebra of the Dynkin quiver $D_4$ and another algebra tilted from it.  That is, let $A$ be the path algebra where the quiver $D_4$ is oriented so that the vertex of degree 3 is a source and let $B$ be the quotient of the path algebra of the Euclidean quiver $\tilde{A}_3$--oriented so that we have two paths of length 2 from a source to a sink--by the relation expressing that these two paths are equal. Then $B$ is biserial (I believe it is even special biserial, if I remember the definition correctly), but $A$ is not biserial.   That these algebras are derived equivalent follows from the fact that one is tilted from the other, which is remarked, for instance, in IV.4.3(b) of Happel's book *Triangulated categories in the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras*.

However, assuming that you mean to include Nakayama algebras (i.e., uniserial algebras) as (special) biserial,  it is true for self-injective special biserial algebras: Pogorzaly shows that this class of algebras is closed under stable equivalence [Comm. Algebra 22 (1994), no. 4, 1127–1160], and derived equivalent self-injective algebras are always stably equivalent by a theorem of Rickard.

Comment: In fact it should read: "each indecomposable projective left or right module" and then your counterexample isn't one anymore, sorry.

Comment: No problem.  I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks, also the reference to Pogorzaly's paper was helpful.

Comment: And yes, it is even special biserial.

Answer (score 3):

Gentle algebras can all be described as path algebras with relations of length $2$, so let's try something with a length $3$ relation.

If you take $k A_4$ with a length $3$ relation you get an algebra derived equivalent to $k D_4$. The first algebra is special biserial, while the other is not biserial.

There is a nice table on page 694 of [Happel, Dieter; Seidel, Uwe. Piecewise hereditary Nakayama algebras. Algebr. Represent. Theory 13 (2010), no. 6, 693--704] which shows the derived equivalence classes you get from $A_n$ with linear orientation and relations of uniform length.